# Check available letters in the middle of word SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, alphabetical

can someone help me with the next issue. I have words database and I need to check availability of the next letters for substring in the middle of word. For example I have few words which have 'gr' in the middle:

```
***gra****
**gre****
****gri****
```

so is it possible to get 'a', 'e', 'i' with sql query? I need these letters for create alphabetical suggestions when user try to find words with 'gr' in the middle?

The way which is working now for me it's run sql query for each letter from a-z for check if any word exists in the database. But it's so many queries and looks weird as for me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple method is `substring_index()` and `left()`:

```
select left(substring_index(col, 'gr', -1), 1)
```

Comment: Thanks this is a good way but it exclude variation when we have repeat 'gr' in a word. For example:
- gra
- agrengri
- testgry
in this way I need to get 'a', 'e', 'i', 'y' but with this query we will lost 'e' :(

Comment: @Crowlex. . . This question is not about repeated patterns but about a single pattern.  if you have another question about multiple patterns in the query, then ask a *new* question.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon for help. Will ask new question about repeated patterns.